# answer the phone

Tags: questions

If I get the call from a job agent, at first, he/she will introduce himself/herself and the agent company name. But, English is not my mother language, I am not sensitive about the person name and other particular name, so, what should I answer the phone politely?

Comment: You may find this [link](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-accept-and-decline-job-offers-498466080) helpful. Also this [one](http://work.chron.com/respond-telephone-job-interview-request-17828.html).

Comment: What would you say in your language? Say just that in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be polite and to ask them to repeat their name and where they are calling from.

"Thank you very much for calling."
"I'm sorry, I didn't catch your name and your company."

The first statement is polite. The second politely asks them to state their name and company name again.

Comment: "Please repeat your name and and your company" sounds a bit robotic - that's what I'd expect a voice recognition program on a help line to say to me. "Could you please repeat that" or "I'm sorry, I didn't catch that" might be better alternatives.

Comment: Point taken, @Damien H.

Comment: Also, if you don't understand something, "Excuse me" is always a good alternative to "I'm sorry."